# Is there a function in SQL Server to convert to a decimal number?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a cell value in a column that is "12,000". And I want to change to "11,000" and display it... but it only displays a blank space. And in the database the value appears NULL.

In the database the type is `Decimal(18,3)`.

My code in C# is like this:

```cs
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(dgvRow.Cells[16].Value.ToString());
string query = "UPDATE cabecdoc SET CDU_Peso = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3),'" + dec + "' ) WHERE Id = '" + idDoc + "'";
```

If I do the query:

```sql
UPDATE CabecDoc 
SET CDU_Peso = TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,3), '11.000') 
WHERE Id = 'fb9668a9-46fa-11ec-9494-00155d01b010'
```

in Microsoft SQL Server - it works... but in my program in C# it displays a blank space value.

Comment: What you state is impossible. `' '` is not a valid `decimal` value and so your column **cannot** have that value. Though you also need to learn about parametrisation; your code is highly dangerous.

Comment: `dgvRow.Cells[16].Value` is the value. Mindlessly coercing it with `ToString` and then `Convert.ToDecimal` is going to mangle it. Erase that pattern from your repretoire. Now. Test its type and write proper handling for each possible type.

Comment: Use a parameterized query and you can pass that decimal.

Comment: Do you know bobby tables? https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, assuming the text value will NOT have the $ (or currency character), then this will work:

```
        string strSQL = "UPDATE cabecdoc " +
                        "SET CDU_Peso = @Peso " +
                        "WHERE Id = @ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Peso", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = dgvRow.Cells[16].Text;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idDoc;
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

So if the cell has:

```
12000
12,000
12,000.00
```

Then the above will work fine.

However, if the cell is to have:

```
 $12,000.00
```

Then you need to use the globalization converters for this.

Say like this:

```
   // -- using System.Globalization;

            Decimal TestNum = 0;
            decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text,
            NumberStyles.Currency,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat, out TestNum);
```

Now, if the converter fails, then the TestNum will not be changed (the "out" return value in above), and then we now have this:

```
        string strSQL = "UPDATE cabecdoc " +
                        "SET CDU_Peso = @Peso " +
                        "WHERE Id = @ID";
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Peso", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = TestNum;
            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = idDoc;
            cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

And while the first will work as long as no currency character such as "$"?

Well, it will work, but first example does not handle "" (empty string).

so, you could say use this:

```
string MyPeso = dgvRow.Cell[16].Text;
if (MyPeso == "")
   MyPeso = "0";

....
cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Peso", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = MyPeso;
```

Also, as noted, not only is using paramters a lot easier - you don't even have to know (or think) if you need to surround the values - so the sql is much easier to read, and as noted, it is sql injection safe.

eg this:

[image]